# How to convert Nginx error.log to json format

Tags: json, nginx, error-log, nginx-log

Is there a way to convert the **error.log** in Nginx to json? I need to ship the logs to an external log viewer, to do that I need to convert the **error.log** to json.

Comment: [`escape=json`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using filebeat may be an alternative depending on were you want to ship your logs (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-output.html)

Comment: You're right, sorry ! Were do you want to ship your error logs though ?

Comment: I'm shipping them to GCP. But I need to create an internal format so converting it to json will make it easy for me.

Comment: Sounds like a proper use case for a filebeat / logstash setup (with filebeat running on the nginx host and sending your logs to a logstash instance/cluster that transforms and ships to GCP using one of the available output plugins)